# Collapsing animation looking weird when collapsing flex-column navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a navigation in the sidebar using the bootstrap 4-framework, which is shown on the top of the page on small devices.

My approach:

```css
.sidebar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(33, 243, 96) 0%, #077710 70%);
}

.sidebar .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
}

.main .top-row {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
}

.nav-item:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.nav-item:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-item a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.nav-item a.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  color: white;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 1.1rem;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}


/* @media (max-width: 767.98px) { */

.main .top-row {
  display: none;
}


/* Burger-icon animation */

.navbar-toggler {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus,
.navbar-toggler:active {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #444;
  height: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1),
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .35s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(2) {
  height: 12px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  opacity: 0.9;
}


/* } */


/* @media (min-width: 768px) {
    contentwrapper {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .main{
        position: absolute;
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
        margin-left: 250px;
        float: right;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .main .top-row {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
    .main > div {
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
    .sidebar .collapse {
        display: block;
    }
} */
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <contentwrapper>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">MyTestPage</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav flex-column collapse" id="navbarContent">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                        Home
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Page1
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Page2
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Page3
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Page4
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <f:render section="Main" />
    </div>
  </contentwrapper>
</body>
```

Note: I commented the media querys in my css, to ensure it is displayed like on a mobile device

If you now click the hamburger-icon to uncollaps the menu you can see that it is first displayed with each of the menu points placed horicontally instead of vertically, and just after about a half second it changes to how it should be.

What was my mistake? If you know a workaround please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Bootstrap4* has a `.nav` class with these rules:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

So we have to override one rule with `flex-wrap:nowrap;`

I don't know if you will use that Bootstrap class in another part of your site, so maybe it is better to override it only for your navigation:

```
#navbarContent.nav{
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
```

I removed also your `@media (max-width: 767.98px) {` (^_^;)... 'cause I think it is not necessary: it's a mobile first site, I think.

BTW, this is the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>

.sidebar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(33, 243, 96) 0%, #077710 70%);
}

.sidebar .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
}

.main .top-row {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
}

.nav-item:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.nav-item:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-item a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.nav-item a.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  color: white;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 1.1rem;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}



.main .top-row {
  display: none;
}


/* Burger-icon animation */

.navbar-toggler {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus,
.navbar-toggler:active {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #444;
  height: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1),
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .35s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(2) {
  height: 12px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#navbarContent.nav{
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}




 @media (min-width: 768px) {
    contentwrapper {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .main{
        position: absolute;
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
        margin-left: 250px;
        float: right;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .main .top-row {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
    .main > div {
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
    .sidebar .collapse {
        display: block;
    }
} 

</style>

<contentwrapper>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">MyTestPage</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav flex-column collapse" id="navbarContent">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                        Home
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Page1
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Page2
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Page3
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        Page4
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <f:render section="Main" />
    </div>
  </contentwrapper>
```